# How to convert type of list from Object to Date without iterate list in java 7

Tags: java, list, date, object, casting

```
List<Object> list = query.list();
for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++) {
    Object[] fields = (Object[]) list.get(i);
    if (fields[1]!=null) {
        dates.add((Date) fields[0]);
    } else {

    }
}
```

Now I want to cast type of list from Object to Date without iterate list.

Comment: If you declare `dates` as a `List<Date>` then you already have what you need.

Comment: I dont think that you can do that.. and you did not defined why you are making an if statement for fields[1], if you have a statement in your iteration how do you expect it to do without an iteration?